# jQuery: share buttons (sharrre) do not work locally and on the server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to use the `sharrre` social media share buttons.

however, I don't understand why this code doesn't work locally OR on my server but it works perfectly fine on jsfiddle!

This is the jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/f7yobj60/

and this is my exact code:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sharrre.com</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Sharrre" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://sharrre.com/js/jquery.sharrre-1.3.4.min.js"></script>
  <script>
$('.share-buttons').each(function() {
    $(this).sharrre({
        share: {
            twitter: true,
            facebook: true
        },
        template: '<div class="share-icon-holder"><a href="#" class="facebook"><img src="http://png-2.findicons.com/files/icons/2052/social_network/32/facebook.png" /></a><a href="#" class="twitter"><img src="http://png.findicons.com/files/icons/2052/social_network/32/twitter.png" /></a></div><div class="share-text">Share</div>',
        enableHover: false,
        enableTracking: false,
        render: function(api, options){
            $(api.element).on('click', '.twitter', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                api.openPopup('twitter');
            });
            $(api.element).on('click', '.facebook', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                api.openPopup('facebook');
            });
        }
    });
});
  </script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="share-buttons" data-url="http://www.google.com" data-text="Google test"></div>
<div class="share-buttons" data-url="http://www.stackoverflow.com" data-text="Stackoverflow test"></div>
<div class="share-buttons" data-url="http://www.google.com" data-text="Google test 2 - long text"></div>
<div class="share-buttons" data-url="http://www.stackoverflow.com" data-text="Stackoverflow test 245345"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

is there anything that I am missing in my HTML page?

I even downloaded  the files from the github and even those files don't work for me locally or on my server!

this is the strangest thing I've ever encountered.

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The buttons don't exist when your code runs, wrap the code in a ready handler so they exist when it does run.

JSfiddle does this automatically for you ... see the option `onload` selected in dropdown at top left

```
$(function(){
  /* your code here */
});
```